# How do I change a float into a string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, floating-point

Im trying to create an attribute generator and i have to store values. The only issue I have is that im storing a float not a string yet I don't know how to change it.

```
score = dtwo/done
print(int (score))
strength=score + initial

myFile = open( name + "'s Strength", 'wt')
myFile.write(strength)
myFile.close()
```

Please help as I am clueless....

Comment: Use the `str` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
myFile.write(str(strength))
```

or this:

```
myFile.write(repr(strength))
```

To specify the number of digits:

```
myFile.write('{0:.5f}'.format(strength))
```

More information about formatting with `str.format` here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Answer (score 0):

Create another variable, which is `strength` in string form. You would use the `str` function.

```
other_variable=str(strength)
```

Then instead of writing strength to `myFile`, use `other_variable` instead.

```
myFile.write(other_variable)
```